# Selenium C# NUnit how to take and save screenshot of failed test into the folder

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, azure-pipelines, nunit

I am new at Selenium and came up with an issue - how to take and save screenshot into the specific folder. I am using Selenium+C#+NUnit bond.

Have read many information on this but most of them is on - how to capture screenshot and add it to html file. But this is not what I need.

I need the screenshot file to be save into a folder so when I'm running Pipeline in AzureDevOps the "Tests results" block contain this screenshot as well and display it.

I was using this part of the code. The test runs and fails, but no screenshot was make

```
[OneTimeTearDown]
public void OneTimeTearDown()
        {
            if (TestContext.CurrentContext.Result.Outcome != ResultState.Failure)
            {
                var screenshot = ((ITakesScreenshot)driver).GetScreenshot();
                var filePath = "pathToTheFolder\\Screenshots\\"; 
                screenshot.SaveAsFile(filePath, Png);
            }
        }
```

Maybe someone can help on this and maybe share the knowledge and the code as well)

Thank you all!

Comment: Hi ,glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! Please consider answering it and accepting it as an answer to change its status to Answered. See [can I answer my own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a way how to reach out my goal - to save screenshots for failed tests in a bin folder of the project and attach them to the Pipeline "Test Result" section in further.
This is the final workable code. I have removed it from [OneTimeTearDown] and set it to [TearDown]. And also have added attachment with the last row, that allows to  sent screenshots to Pipelines "Test result" block.

This is my Base.cs file where I am locating IWebDriver, all Setup and TearDown methods

```
using E2E_Tests.TestData;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using WebDriverManager.DriverConfigs.Impl;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using System.Configuration;
using NUnit.Framework.Interfaces;

        [TearDown]
        
                public void TearDown()
                {
                    TakeScreenshotDefaultImageFormat();
                    driver.Close();
                }
                public void TakeScreenshotDefaultImageFormat()
                {
                    
                    if (TestContext.CurrentContext.Result.Outcome == ResultState.Error)
                    {
                        var screenshot = ((ITakesScreenshot)driver).GetScreenshot();
                        var screenshotDirectoryPath = Path.Combine(TestContext.CurrentContext.TestDirectory, "Screenshots\\");
                        if (!Directory.Exists(screenshotDirectoryPath))
                        {
                            Directory.CreateDirectory(screenshotDirectoryPath);
                        }
                        var currentDate = DateTime.Now;
                        var filePath = $"{screenshotDirectoryPath}{TestContext.CurrentContext.Test.Name}_{currentDate.ToString("yyyy.MM.dd-HH.mm.ss")}.png";
                        screenshot.SaveAsFile(filePath);
                        TestContext.AddTestAttachment(filePath);
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```cs
using System.Drawing; //add this using statement

[OneTimeTearDown]
public void OneTimeTearDown()
{
    if (TestContext.CurrentContext.Result.Outcome != ResultState.Failure)
    {
        var screenshot = ((ITakesScreenshot)driver).GetScreenshot();
        var filePath = "pathToTheFolder\\Screenshots\\"; 
        screenshot.SaveAsFile(filePath + System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
    }
}
```

[This tutorial](https://www.agilequalitymadeeasy.com/post/capturing-screenshots-with-selenium-webdriver-c) looks like what you need

Comment: Thank you @Narish for you answer! It guide me to the right path! And the article is useful too. Explanation will be in a comment below)

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this and work fine within getting casename and counting the failed screenshot:

```
public void Take_screen_shot_for_failed_case(string ScreenShotOutputPath)
    {
        var RuningCaseName = TestContext.CurrentContext.Test.FullName;
        if (TestContext.CurrentContext.Result.Status != TestStatus.Passed)
        {
            try
            {
                DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(ScreenShotOutputPath);
                if (!dirInfo.Exists)
                {
                    dirInfo.Create();
                }

                var shortCaseName = RuningCaseName.Substring(RuningCaseName.LastIndexOf('.') + 1);

                var screenshot = ((ITakesScreenshot)driver).GetScreenshot();
                var screenshotDirectoryPath = Path.Combine(dirInfo.FullName);
                if (!Directory.Exists(screenshotDirectoryPath))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(screenshotDirectoryPath);
                }
                var existingFile = dirInfo.GetFiles(shortCaseName + "_*.png", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
                string filePath = Path.Combine(dirInfo.FullName, string.Format("{0}_[{1}].png", shortCaseName, existingFile.Length + 1));
                screenshot.SaveAsFile(filePath, ScreenshotImageFormat.Png);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }    
    }
```